# Stream Video from Raspberry Pi to Android app

Tags: java, android, video, video-streaming, raspberry-pi2

I am trying to stream video from a webcam on a raspberry pi to an android application. I used motion library on the raspberry pi to stream the video. This worked fine as I can see the video on my browser by navigating to http://raspberrypiIP:8081.

Question: how do I display this video on an Android app?
I went for LibVLC, but I am on windows environment and the lib cannot be built. I wanted to try GStreamer but I am not used to native libraries.

Are there some java libraries enabling this or other easier ways that enables me to view the video on an Android phone?

I'm using Android Studio and I'm quite new to Android development.

Answer (score 0):

I have not yet attempted to stream from Raspberry Pi to Android. However, I have streamed from Raspberry Pi to YouTube Live Events (https://www.youtube.com/my_live_events) which is easy to set up and get working.

I have also used the Android YouTube API Player API to play YouTube videos inside some of my Android apps (https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/).

So, I recommend the YouTube approach as a first line of enquiry.